# Is income earned in the Carribbean considered taxable for a Canadian resident?

Tags: taxes, canada, canada-revenue-agency

If in winter time, I go to Caribbean and make some money as a sailboat instructor, is that money tax free? I am Canadian resident. I am asking this because I hear  that a lot of these Caribbean islands are 'tax free'. Does it differ from island to island? Let us say I am going to Jamaica / Barbados

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Canadian resident then yes, it is taxable to you. The islands don't have income taxes on income earned there, but your country does. If you lose your Canadian residency and move to live in these islands, then the answer may change.